# Kusto - extract key value from the Kusto table result

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

How do I extract a set of key value from Kusto Table result. I have a Data field (column in Kusto table) that has log details (15 lines with time stamp). Out of these 15 lines, the last 3 lines has a key value pair which I will need to use in the Query to filter and display results.

Do I use the below method can you give some examples

Extract values on column with strings sharing the same format or pattern -

Example Values from column are (last 3 lines from the Data section)

````
2021-09-05T06:42:19.2287304Z VMtype - C4
2021-09-05T06:42:19.2287304Z patchsizeMB - 2533```

I am trying with the below Query is this the right way of doing

```| parse Data with * "Virtual machine =" Virtual machine 
| parse Data with * "VMtype=" VMtype
| parse Data with * "patchsizeMB=" patchsizeMB```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way that you implemented it is fine, easiest to understand, and maintain.

Here is a full example, where the results are returned in one row for each timestamp:

```
datatable(Data:string)["2021-09-05T06:42:19.2287304Z VMtype - C4",
                       "2021-09-05T06:42:19.2287304Z patchsizeMB - 2533",
                       "2021-09-05T06:42:19.2287304Z Virtual machine - VM_Name"]
| parse Data with Timestemp:datetime " " *
| parse Data with * "Virtual machine -" VirtualMachine 
| parse Data with * "VMtype -" VMtype
| parse Data with * "patchsizeMB -" patchsizeMB
| summarize take_any(VirtualMachine), take_any(VMtype), take_any(patchsizeMB) by bin(Timestemp, 1d)
```

Results:

| Timestemp | VirtualMachine | VMtype | patchsizeMB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-05 | VM_Name | C4 | 2533 |

You can also implement it by splitting the string into an array and working on the array to populate the appliable values but it is much more code and probably more fragile.

Comment: I was able to extract the fields but I have a new challenge. The parsed value does not appear in the same row. For example, in the Table I can see 3 rows for the col 1 - project name for which col2 - Virtual machine  , col3 - VMtype, col4 - patchsizeMB appears in different rows. So I could not use strcat to combine the Virtual machine+VMtype as they appear in diff rows.

How do I combine Virtual machine+VMtype and list the patch size value for each project 

I did research on serialize, next() but could not progress . Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Yes, this is expected since the data is in different rows. You can probably use summarize + take_any() by timestamp assuming that it is the same. I modified my answer with an example.

Comment: thanks . I just added Date format like below because the data was appearing in same date (Hours & minutes) but diff seconds. So added date format and removed the seconds and milli seconds so it worked perfect. Thanks.

```| extend Timestamp = format_datetime(Timestamp,'yy-MM-dd [HH:mm]')```

Comment: A better way to do it is by using the "bin()" function:
 |  summarize take_any(VirtualMachine), take_any(VMtype), take_any(patchsizeMB) by bin(Timestemp, 1m)

Comment: Could you please tell me how do I create a graph that will have Y axis as timestamp, x axis as Package size and with the line representing the package size for VM (Win & Linux) . 

for below Query it says - Error bin(): argument #1 - invalid data type: string. 
`T | where stepName contains "PackageSize" 
| parse Data with * "VmType=" VmType 
| parse Data with * "PackageSize=" PackageSize
| parse Data with Timestamp:datetime " " * 
| extend Timestamp = format_datetime(Timestamp,'yy-MM-dd [HH:mm]') 
| summarize take_any(PackageSize) by VmType, bin(Timestamp, 1d) 
| render timechart`

Comment: what happens when you remove this line
| extend Timestamp = format_datetime(Timestamp,'yy-MM-dd [HH:mm]')

Comment: I update my example in the answer

Comment: Below is the complete Query. when i remove the format date time, I am unable to parse the data needed to create the filters. 

`BuildLogs
| where stepName contains "PackageSize"
| parse Data with Timestamp:datetime " " * 
| extend Timestamp = format_datetime(Timestamp,'yy-MM-dd [HH:mm]')
| parse Data with * "VMType=" VMType
| parse Data with * "VMSize=" VMSize
| parse Data with * "PackageSize=" PackageSize
| summarize take_any(VMType), take_any(VMSize), take_any(PackageSize) by Timestamp
| where VMSize has "C4"
| extend Legend = strcat(VMType,"_", VMSize)`

Comment: Can you send an example using datatable()? (i.e. replace BuildLogs with datatable()) Without an example it is hard to tell what is the issue here

Comment: Thanks. Below is the current Data table . Legend has 2 values - Win C4 & Linux C4 . I would like to seperate these values into 2 columns and create line chart for the Patch size for these 2 Legends in 1d timespan


Timestamp  & VirtualMachine & VMtype & PatchSize & Legend VM+VMType \\
2021-09-05 & Windows        & C4     & 2533      & WindowsC4        \\
2021-09-05 & Linux          & C4     & 3152      & LinuxC4          \\
2021-09-06 & Windows        & C4     & 4156      & WindowsC4        \\
2021-09-06 & Linux          & C4     & 3555      & LinuxC4

Comment: Sorry for the format as I am not sure how to insert as a table.

Comment: Please create a datatable() statement and update your question to include it (or just take the example in my question and update it to fit your scenario)

Comment: Updated from your example with sample data table

Comment: I have completed the task . Thanks much for the support.

Comment: I saw in your edit that you pasted an image, this is not good since I can't copy and paste it into my own editor, can you please copy and paste it? thanks !

Comment: Sorry for that. I am not sure if I have any limitations . I get the Tables option only whn I create a new question. Anyways I had resolved the task completely and Thanks for the support.

Comment: Great! To make your questions easier to answer, please add example/s using the datatable() code snippet and supporting images, we are really happy to support!